# Smoked multiple H bridges, don't know why

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, h-bridge, mosfet-driver

I am currently developing a self-driving slot-car.

For driving the DC motor, I am using a ROHM Semicon BD6231F-E2 H bridge (datasheet: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810241113_ROHM-Semicon-BD6231F-E2_C253180.pdf).

The setup worked perfectly fine on our test track, however on a different track (even though same voltage) I already smoked two H bridges without knowing why. The work fine at first and smoke after a seemingly random amount of time.
I have the feeling that it smokes after the motor gets blocked, but as far as I understand the datasheet the H bridge has OCP, so I don't understand why this should happen.

The circuit looks as follows, the cable leaving to the right is the 14V line. FIN and RIN are connected to an ESP32, with RIN low and FIN providing a PWM signal:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Did you read the requirements for the chip - do not exceed Power dissipation (Pd) and ASO (area of safe operation)? Have you calculated the power dissipation for your chip and load? You might need to implement stall and overload detection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I unfortunately don't know how much current our motor draws exactly. I found some website claiming it to draw 100mA, which is way less than the 500mA max of the H-Bridge.
How would I calculate the power that the h-bridge itself generates, so I could check power dissipation?

Comment: Measure! Assuming it is a little brushed motor, measure the stall current (as in apply full voltage to the motor, but stop it from turning). Note - the h bridge doesn’t generate power - it wastes it. As heat. Once we know the max motor current we can estimate how hot the h hridge might get. Other possible causes of failure might be voltage spikes. It might be necessary to put a varistor across the input of the car.